# SQL Syntax with Updating 2nd table on 1st table insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to issue a mysqli_multi_query, in which my querys are named $query & $query2.  Query 1 is a seperate table from query 2.  This is a sample of how the code syntax looks like:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO invoices (`id`,`c`) VALUES (NULL, '$client_id')";
$query2 = "UPDATE `customers` SET `a` = `$a`,`b` = `$b` WHERE `customers.id` = $client_id";
```

the invoices.client_id is the same as the customers.id, and I only want to update customers.id that matches the invoice client_id.

For some odd reason, everything is updated fine into my invoices, but not into my customers.  Is my syntax correct?

Comment: if you add a semi-colon after  `$client_id')`, does it work?

Comment: you really need to use prepared statements in the first place but, having backticks on `$a` messes it up

Comment: there is already a semicolon after $client_id')";

Comment: is `$client_id` a string? On the insert you treat it as a string, on the update you don't.

Comment: $client_id is an integer

Comment: but is the field `customers.id` also an `int`? In `invoices` it seems to be not . But go for @Ghost's comments first!

Comment: Is this what you mean by prepared statements? $a = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $data['data']['Invoice']['a'] ) );

Comment: no. see here: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @Ghost fixed the backticks"converted to '$a'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100714/discussion-between-steven-and-jeff).

Comment: these `customers.id` must be ticked seperately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after our discussion in the chat we figured out the following misstakes:

Your code:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE customers SET alarmcode = $alarmcode, garagecode = $garagecode, gatecode = $gatecode, liason = $liason, lphone = $lphone WHERE customers.id = '$client_id'";
```

table-def:

[image]

So the problem was not correct encapsulating of strings in the sql statement.

corrected statement was:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE customers SET alarmcode = '$alarmcode', garagecode = '$garagecode', gatecode = '$gatecode', liason = '$liason', lphone = '$lphone' WHERE id = $client_id";
```